# unable to set live wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I have create an application in android 2.x , in which there are few activities and a livewallpaper service which creates live wallpaper

so after building and running the whole application in a simulator , if i access Livewallpaper from Livewallpaper picker and try to set my created live wallpaper i encountered following error.

and i really don't know what its saying as i have removed the BIND_WALLPAPER permission also

```
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373): Failure setting wallpaper
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373): java.lang.SecurityException: Selected service does not require android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER: ComponentInfo{com.vb.ui/com.vb.ui.CWallpaper}
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at android.app.IWallpaperManager$Stub$Proxy.setWallpaperComponent(IWallpaperManager.java:210)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at com.android.wallpaper.livepicker.LiveWallpaperPreview.setLiveWallpaper(LiveWallpaperPreview.java:95)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 WARN/LiveWallpaperPreview(373):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show your manifest, where did you add the permission?

Comment: <permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"></permission> This is the tag which is added inside manifest tag